# PDE basic traffic flow problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics

I am analyzing a basic example of traffic flow presented here
http://people.uncw.edu/hermanr/pde1/PDEbook/PDE_Main.pdf
and have a question to the last transition in the traffic flow equation derivation. (Example 1.7)

Given are: 
density function $ \ u(x,t) \ $ expressed in cars/miles, $ \ \ $ velocity v in miles/hour, $ \ $ and $ \ \ \phi(x,t) \ $ expressed in cars per hour.

The relation can be described as
$$\phi(x,t)=uv$$
assuming constant relation between velocity and density
$$v=v_1- \frac{v_1}{u_1} u$$
substituting for v gives
$$\phi=uv=v_1 (u-\frac{u^2}{u_1})$$

**Now there is the equation for the car density written as 
$$0=u_t + \phi' u_x$$

which I don't understand. Where does it mathematically come from? where the $u_t$ comes from here?**

should be the below equation applied here? How?
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}=\frac{d \phi}{d u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$

Comment: I think the explanation is on pg. 11.  $\phi' = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}$. Generally speaking, the conservation law is $\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{\partial u}{dt} + \frac{\partial \phi}{dx}$.

Comment: @ player100  why $\phi' = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}$ ?

Comment: In general the "continuity equation" or "transport equation" is $u_t+v u_x=0$ (or, in higher dimensions, $u_t + v \cdot \nabla_x u = 0$.) Apparently in their notation they intend $\phi'=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}$ (just a notational choice), so that $\phi'=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(uv)=v$.

Comment: @ Ian I understand that $f(x,y)$ denoted as the source density equals zero here, therefore the equation 1.28  is of the form $u_t + \phi_x = 0$, but I don't get the following substitutions.  $$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}=\frac{d \phi}{d u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$ Where this came from ?

Comment: So actually, the proper form of the conservation law is $u_t + \operatorname{div}_x(\phi)=0$, where $\phi=uv$ is the flux. So since this is 1D, you want the total derivative of $\phi$ with respect to $x$ (where $\phi$ is understood only as a function of $x$ here.) But in your setting, $\phi$ is given as a function of $u$. So to differentiate it with respect to $x$, you use the chain rule: $\frac{d \phi}{dx} = \frac{d \phi}{du} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$.

Comment: The confusing thing here is that the two functions $\phi$ that we're talking about here represent the same quantity, but with a different independent variable, which means they are not actually the same mathematical function. This is convenient and common in this sort of PDE theory: for example, we write $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ for a partial derivative at a single point and then we write $\frac{du}{dt}$ for a change in $u$ along the path of a characteristic.

Comment: I am confused here with the way the chain rule was used. 1) $\frac{d \phi}{dx} = \frac{d \phi}{du} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ which is equivalent to $\phi(x)'= \phi(u)' u_x$ or 2)  $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ equivalent to $\phi_x=  \phi_u  u_x$  There is $\phi_x$ in the equation 1.28, why then  $\frac{d \phi}{dx}$ 1)  is used for substitution and not  $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$ 2) ?

Comment: Let's think physically for a second. The continuity equation tells us that, if we measure $u$ at a fixed point, the rate at which it changes in time is $-\operatorname{div}_x(\phi)$. In other words, material *escapes* at rate $\operatorname{div}_x(\phi)$. This divergence should be the total divergence of $\phi$, so that the divergence theorem (in 1D, integration by parts) makes sense.

Comment: If $\phi$ is initially given as a function of $u$, then this means $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\phi(u(t,x+\Delta x))-\phi(u(t,x))}{\Delta x}$ which is by the 1D chain rule $\frac{d \phi}{du} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$.